# problem of power on PIN 1 and PIN 2 of DIN connector of Roomba 521

Tags: irobot-create, power

I notice there is a problem of power on PIN 1 and PIN 2 of DIN connector of Roomba 521...I have only 0,5 V but it's expected 12V...motherboard damaged?

Comment: why are you assuming that the motherboard is damaged? ... check the battery

Answer (score 1):

I find right answer:

with connected broken buck converter I measured 0V, but removing broken buck converter all work fine and I can measure 12V.

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when you don’t use both power pins together, in order to get full voltage both pins must terminate into 1 wire or trace.

Comment: I used only PIN1 for 1 months with full 12V....you suggest to join PIN 1 and PIN2 in parallel? I have to do the same with ground PINs?

Comment: Yes I had the same issues when first attempting to use the battery to power a micro, in the end I joined both power pins in parallel and both ground pins in parallel, now I get a stable voltage into the regulator at all times.